# Как можно засунуть программу Python в программу, пусть даже самую простую

Tags: python

У меня есть простой код на генерацию пароля для пользователя. Мне очень интересно отправить данный код своим друзьям, но не запуская его через интерпретатор, а в программе. Какие есть варианты это сделать, быть может, посоветуете какие-нибудь библиотеки и тд.

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/vdsina/blog/557316/

Comment: для этого есть pyinstaller. Думаю в поиске легко найдете

Answer (score 0):

Можете на flask или Django сверстать простой сайт; ещё вариант создать приложение на телефон (Kivy); можно сделать приложение для пк (Tkinter)

Comment: А как Вы предлагаете это передать причем не нагружая юзера дополнительными установками(самого python и тд.. )?